# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 even though I think I meet them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow2.0

I am following a tutorial and I used pip install tensorflow for that. Now I realize that things changed over the years and things got named differently because I am getting the error `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'` and I heard that is because things used to be different in tensorflow 1.x . Now I want tried to install tensorflow using `pip install tensorflow==1.15` but I get the error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4, 2.4.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15
```

And I don't really know why? Did anybody else experience this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to use `python 3.8` which was not officially supported when tensorflow was at version `1.15`.

You can choose python version between `3.5` to `3.7` or `2.7`, your issue can be resolved.

You can also check download files on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.15.0/#files), there are no files available for cp38 for `tensorflow 1.15`.

*Note: You need a 64-bit version of Python, in case if are using a 32-bit version.*