# Unable for install tensorflow version 1 with PIP

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting an error while installing tensorflow-1.15==gpu version.

```sh
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15.0 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15.0
```

while There is no issue with tensorflow latest version.

Comment: I guess you are trying to use `python 3.8` which was not officially supported when tensorflow was at version `1.15`. You can choose python version between `3.5` to `3.7` or `2.7`, your issue can be resolved. For more details you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66245192/14290681). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It solved by using python3.6.

Comment: @CodePerfectPlus Can you add that as an answer so we can mark https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72403255/how-to-install-specific-tensorflow-version-on-windows-10-using-pip-not-using-con as a duplicate of this one?