# How to install specific tensorflow version on windows 10 using pip not using conda?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to install TensorFlow 1.15 version on my machine windows 10. I don't have anaconda so I can't use conda commands, I need a solution in pip.

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (from versions: 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15

Comment: See the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66399282/unable-for-install-tensorflow-version-1-with-pip (I can't mark as duplicate because there is no accepted answer there)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to install it in python between 3.5 and 3.7 versions.